# Sort matrix with NaNs, extract index vectors and move NaNs to the end

Tags: matlab, sorting, nan

`mockup = [3,5,nan,2,4,nan,10,nan];`

How can I sort this vector in a descending order while ignoring the NaNs? The resulting vector must have the same length as `mockup`, i.e. I need to put all NaNs at the end. The result should like like this:
`mockupSorted = [10,5,4,3,2,NaN,NaN,NaN]`

Actually, I am interested in the respective indices, i.e. the second output vector of the `sort` function. So, I am looking for
`mockupSortedIdx = [7,2,5,1,4,NaN,NaN,NaN]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the two outputs of `sort` and then use `isnan` to modify the ordering of the two outputs.

```
[vals, inds] = sort(mockup, 'descend');

bool = isnan(vals);

mocksorted = [vals(~bool), vals(bool)];
%    10     5     4     3     2   NaN   NaN   NaN

mocksortedind = [inds(~bool), vals(bool)];
%     7     2     5     1     4   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

The other option is to use `ascend` sort and just sort the negative of `mockup` since the `ascend` sort will place the `NaN` values at the end.

```
[vals, inds] = sort(-mockup);

mocksorted = -vals;
mocksortedind = inds;
```

Comment: This solution is quite handy! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The solution works quite well when working with row vectors (as I put it in my original question). However, in reality I am working with 2D/3D matrices and I need to apply the sorting to every row. But there is a dimension problem when concatenating the indices and the NaN values.

Can you please use this 3D mockup matrix:

`mockup(:,:,1) = ...
    [100, 100, 100; ...
    103, 95, 100; ...
    101, 85, 100; ...
    96, 90, 102];

mockup(:,:,2) = ...
    [50, NaN, NaN; ...
    47, NaN, 40; ...
    45, 60, 45; ...
    47, 65, 45];`

Comment: @Andi for more complicated matrices just use my second suggestion